# Sorting array, and selecting field in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, sorting, aggregate

I'm trying to transform the following data using `MongoDB` aggregation. I want the `array` 'connections' sorted and I only want the array-elements that have a name matching my regex.

In this case I want the `array` sorted on 'steps' (number of intermediare friends) and only those with 'Han' in their name. This would result in 'Han Solo' in this example.

Both the `sort` and `match2` operation don't do what I expect them to. The array isn't sorted, and not matched at all... What did I do wrong? Any additional feedback on this is welcome, first time I'm using `MongoDB` in `Java`.

Thanks!

```
{
"name": "Luke Skywalker",
"_id": 1,
"connections": [
    {
        "name": "Tendra Risant",
        "_id": 5,
        "steps": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Han Solo",
        "_id": 2,
        "steps": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Leia Organa",
        "_id": 3,
        "steps": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Luke Skywalker",
        "_id": 1,
        "steps": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Lando Clarissian",
        "_id": 4,
        "steps": 1
    }
]
}


public List<DBObject> search(final int id, final String value) {
    AggregationOperation graphlookup = new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
            DBObject graphLookup = new BasicDBObject("from", "people")
                    .append("startWith", "$friends") //start at friends array
                    .append("connectFromField", "friends") //Links a value from the array friends to the ...
                    .append("connectToField", "_id") // ... id of a following document -> creating a chain of friends
                    .append("maxDepth",3)
                    .append("depthField","steps")
                    .append("as", "connections");
            return new BasicDBObject("$graphLookup", graphLookup);
        }
    };

    AggregationOperation project = new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
            DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("connections.name", 1)
                            .append("connections._id", 1)
                            .append("connections.steps", 1)
                            .append("name", 1);
            return new BasicDBObject("$project", match);
        }
    };

    AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));
    AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "connections.steps");
    AggregationOperation match2 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("connections.name").regex(".*Han.*"));

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(graphlookup, project, sort, match, match2);
    List<DBObject> output = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "people", DBObject.class).getMappedResults();
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant sort the array in place. So you require to `$unwind + $sort/$match + $group`.

Change last few lines of code to

```
 AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(1));
 AggregationOperation unwind = Aggregation.unwind("connections");
 AggregationOperation match2 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("connections.name").regex(".*Han.*"));
 AggregationOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "connections.steps");
 AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("_id").push("connections").as("connections").first("name").as("name");
 AggregationOperation project2 = Aggregation.project("connections").andExclude("_id").andInclude(Fields.from(Fields.field("name", "id")));
```